# how to modify view page value in yii2?

Tags: yii2

In yii2 View contains the value from database.  want modify the value as userdefined value, for example database value is 1, i want to show yes.

```
[
        'attribute'=>'status',
        'value'=>if(Status==1){ return 'yes' }else{return 'No' },
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use if condition inside the detail view.Using conditional operator
Try this below code,

```
 [
  'attribute'=>'status',

  'value'=>$model->status=='1'? 'Yes':'no', ],
```